# How to install mysql on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mysql

I am running a Ubuntu 15.10.
I know it's not supported anymore but still is there a way to install mysql 5.6 on it?
I have found any post that could help me.

**[UPDATE]**

here is the error I get:

Like 15.10 is not supported anymore I guess the repos doesn't exist anymore...?

```
Err http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main libaio1 amd64 0.3.110-1
  404  Not Found [IP : 194.158.119.186 80]
Err http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main mysql-common all 5.6.31-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP : 194.158.119.186 80]
Err http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main libdbi-perl amd64 1.633-1
  404  Not Found [IP : 194.158.119.186 80]
Err http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main libdbd-mysql-perl amd64 4.028-2
  404  Not Found [IP : 194.158.119.186 80]
Err http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main libterm-readkey-perl amd64 2.33-1
  404  Not Found [IP : 194.158.119.186 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main mysql-common all 5.6.31-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
```

Comment: You are going to want to go to [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) They will be able to help you... here´s a link you might find useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/203330/how-to-install-mysql-5-6

Answer (score 0):

To overcome such problems easily, there is containerization technology.

If it is possible to install docker on the system, you could start a docker container with the desired version of mySQL:

```
mkdir /my/own/datadir
docker run -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.6
```

This will start an mySQL instance in a docker container with port 3306 exposed (default mySQL port), and mounts the data volume to /my/own/datadir (please change this).

Please note that there are more elegant ways to start this container, this is just an example.

See here for a docker primer: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

See here for the official mysql images: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL on Linux Ubuntu 15 issue the following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```